# jquery datatable cannot change image on hidden columns

Tags: jquery, image, datatables, refresh

I am using jquery datatable responsive.
When i have a big monitor all the cells are showed and I can change src of image using javascript easly, but when i use a monitor that resize my datatable and hide some cloulmns if i change the src value of an image on a hidden columns (showed by clicking on plus icon) the image dont change, neither the src attribute.
[Here is an example of hidden columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKaJK.png)

Follow the datatable init:

```
$(function() {
        table = $('#DT_ADS').
        DataTable({
            "language": {
                "url": "plugins/datatables/localizations/italian.json"
            },
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 15],
            "pageLength": 5,
            "order": [
                [8, "desc"]
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                { targets: "_all",className: "ALING_CENTER"}
              ],
            "sAjaxSource": "ajax/get_ads_datatable.ajax.php",

        });
    });
```

Can someone help me?

EDIT:
The image is a switch, when i click on it I call a function that perform an ajax call and then  edit the src of image to display the correct image inherent in the new changed value.

NOTE:
If i send the element to the function

```
<img id="my_img_1" src="path/of/image.jpg" onclick="changeSrc(this)" /> 
function changeSrc(elem){
elem.src="path/of/image_2.jpg";
}
```

it work also on responsive mode and it change the image succesfully, but i don't undestand why if i try to change the src using

```
document.getElementById("my_img_1").src="path/of/image_2.jpg";
```

it does not work;
seems that the datatable create 2 element of my image and using getElementById i can access only to first that are not displayed

Comment: Your ids are unique??

Comment: Yes, my ids are unique, but i think jquery datatable create another element with same id for hidden rows... becuse if i change in inspector the id of one hidden element i can take it and i can change src and older id still exist somewhere, i would post an example this afternoon when i come back to home so you can check. Thank you for help